# What's the meaning of " usual that year "?

Tags: meaning

I came across this sentence

> But the snow came earlier than usual that year.

This is from a novel. I can understand it if it is "usual years". What's the meaning of " usual that year "?

Comment: You are parsing the sentence incorrectly. You should be asking 'what does the phrase "earlier than usual" mean?' You could rearrange the sentence as: *But, that year, the snow came earlier than usual.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mick mentions, you can rewrite the sentence as:

> That year, the snow came earlier than usual.

The idiom "[X-comparative] than usual" simply means "more X than is normal or typical".  It's a common phrase:

> Her grades were *better than usual* this term.
>
> The tomatoes are *riper than usual* at the market.
>
> I went to bed *later than usual* last night.

And so on.

If I wanted to pair a word like "usual" with "year" I could write something like this:

> The snows came earlier than in a typical year.

Here I compare this year to a *usual* year, but the meaning is the same.

Comment: Thank you for helpful answer. I got it. I misunderstood the structure as "usual" modifies " that year ",